# Gamma random variable , need to find the approximate 90th percentile of X?

Tags: distribution

A colleague defines a random variable $X = \frac{Z}{Y^2}$, where $Z$ is a known normal random variable, $Y$ is a known gamma random variable, and $Z$ and $Y$ are independent of each other.

You are not able to get an analytical form for the cumulative distribution function for $X$, but you need to find the approximate 90th percentile of $X$. How do you go about doing this?

Comment: I started with understanding gamma random variable but got stuck in understanding it.

Comment: What's "Y2"? Y times 2? Y-squared? Gamma with 2 df?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Simulate from Z and Y, compute X, compute empirical percentiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  R:

```
> Z = function(n){rnorm(n)} # normal(0,1) here
> Y = function(n){rgamma(n,10,10)} # some gamma variable
> quantile(Z(100000)/Y(100000)^2,.9) # 100000 from your target dist
     90% 
1.635033
```

So 90% of the values are less than 1.635